# Eclipse plugin development: how to create default folder on start of eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, directory, project-explorer

Creating an eclipse plugin. When I run my plugin, there should be some *default folders* already in the *project explorer*.

The idea is those folder are basically libraries which I can share with all the project created in *project explorer*.

Comment: You can't have folders which are not in projects.

Comment: What kind of libraries? Why do they need to be in the workspace?

Comment: basically they will be the link to those libraries which are physically present on user system.

Comment: @greg-449 so can i create those library folders as projects on startup of plugin?

Comment: It sounds like a [Project Nature](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_natures.htm) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial [here](https://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/)

```
 public static IProject createProject(String projectName, URI location) {
    Assert.isNotNull(projectName);
    Assert.isTrue(projectName.trim().length() &gt; 0);

    IProject project = createBaseProject(projectName, location);
    try {
        addNature(project);

        String[] paths = { "parent/child1-1/child2", "parent/child1-2/child2/child3" }; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        addToProjectStructure(project, paths);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        project = null;
    }

    return project;
}
```

Follow the tutorial in the above link , its quite good for complete project developent

Though you havent asked this , but if there is a need for prewritten files in the project created by plugin. Use this code for achieving that

```
    IFile htaccess=project.getFile("--.htaccess");
String contents = sb.toString();
InputStream sourceone = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());

htaccess.create(sourceone, false, null);
```

Hope it helps.